# Change global ext property in gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to write a build script for different environments. But the global property is not updated for specific tasks.
Here is the script:

```
ext {
    springProfilesActive = 'development'
    angularAppBasePath = '/test/'
}

task setActiveProfiles {
    doLast {
        if (project.hasProperty('activeProfiles')) {
            springProfilesActive = project.property('activeProfiles')
        }
    }
}

task setProperties(dependsOn: ':setActiveProfiles') {
    doLast {
        if (springProfilesActive != 'development') {
            angularAppBasePath = '/'
        }
        println springProfilesActive
        println angularAppBasePath
    }
}

task buildAngular(type: Exec, dependsOn: ':setProperties') {
    workingDir angularPath
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "npm run build.prod -- --base ${angularAppBasePath}"
}
```

If I run `buildAngular -PactiveProfiles=integration` the properies are correctly set. But the `angularAppBasePath` is still the old `/test/` value in the npm command. Output:

```
Executing external task 'buildAngular -PactiveProfiles=integration'...
:setActiveProfiles
:setProperties
integration
/
:buildAngular

> angular-seed@0.0.0 build.prod C:\myapp\src\main\angular
> gulp build.prod --color --env-config prod --build-type prod "--base" "/test/"
```

Why the propery are changed in the `setProperties` task but remains the old value in the `buildAngular` task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rewrite your `setActiveProfiles` and `setProperties` tasks as follows:

```
task setActiveProfiles {
    if (project.hasProperty('activeProfiles')) {
        springProfilesActive = project.property('activeProfiles')
    }
}

task setProperties(dependsOn: ':setActiveProfiles') {
    if (springProfilesActive != 'development') {
        angularAppBasePath = '/'
    }
    println springProfilesActive
    println angularAppBasePath
}
```

This behavior is caused by different build lifecycles. You modify your variable during execution phase (within `doLast` closure), but use it at the configuration phase, which happens just before the execution.You can read about build lifecycle in the [Gradle official user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html).

Comment: Unfortunately this change had no effect.

Comment: For sure, `setProperties` task should be executed at the configuration too. Just forgot to add it to the code snippet